# different behaviour for enums and all other types

Tags: c++11, enums, type-traits

Using gcc-4.8 with -std=c++11 I want to create a template function with one behaviour for enums and other behaviour for all other types. I try this

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
void f(T& /*t*/)
{
    std::cout << "enum" << std::endl;
}

template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
void f(T& /*t*/) {
    std::cout << "not enum" << std::endl;
}

enum class E
{
    A,
    B
};

int main()
{
    E e;
    f(e);
    return 0;
}
```

but compiler returns

```
1.cpp:11:6: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class> void f(T&)’
 void f(T& /*t*/) {
      ^
1.cpp:5:6: error: ‘template<class T, class> void f(T&)’ previously declared here
 void f(T& /*t*/)
      ^
```

I can comment out first template, it leads to compile error, and it's expectable.
And I also can comment out second template, in this case code code can be compiled.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: The two templates have exactly the same signature except for the default template arguments, so you are redefining it rather than declaring an overload. Similar to how you can't "overload" functions whose only difference is the value of default arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because compiler sees them as the same function template, instead, you should do this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type = true>
void f(T& /*t*/)
{
    std::cout << "enum" << std::endl;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type = true>
void f(T& /*t*/) {
    std::cout << "not enum" << std::endl;
}

enum class E
{
    A,
    B
};

int main()
{
    E e;
    f(e);
    return 0;
}
```